# AIR SDK 15.0 + iOS8 - Google Analytics crashes app

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, google-analytics, air

Using Adobe AIR new Beta SDK 15.0.
When using google analytics for AIR :
(analytics.swc + analytics_flash.swc)

```
            com.google.analytics.AnalyticsTracker   
            and   
            com.google.analytics.GATracker
```

This is the error I get:
"ga.js not found, be sure to check if

is included in the HTML."

This started only after using SDK 15.0.
Using SDK 14.0 was successful.

Please advise,
All help appreciated.

Comment: had the same issue with some swc and ANEs, first - try the latest SDK, if not help - recompile swc with the same SDK.

Comment: Did you mean debug mode or adhoc? If you tell about adhoc/appstore modes, note that is little bug occured: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3835447

Comment: Hi fsbmain, can you tell me how can I recompile a swc ? thanks

Comment: @Selirion I mean appstore mode. The link you provided has no walkaround / solution, can you provide one please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > I mean appstore mode.

As I note before problem is in new compilation mechanism which is default in AIR 15 (https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3835447). Add line

```
-useLegacyAOT yes
```

to your compile command line before sign parameters.

Maybe Adobe will fix it in next builds, but now it's only one way to compile your app without recompile SWCs.